# What's wrong with this question? How should I re-phrase it so it will receive views and answers?

Tags: discussion

Here's a question I have put on 5 months ago:

[How do I display X keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/q/684687/181242)

I wanted to know if there's an indicator that I can put that will show me current X keyboard layout.

In 5 months, the question has received 30 views and no answers nor comments. Why so? How do I re-phrase such question differently?

Comment: Bounty? Edit to include what you have tried in the last 5 months.

Comment: I'll quickly ru out of karma for offering bounty on trivial questions like this, and it's not like there's a way to buy some. I thought maybe I'm asking it wrong?

I'll definitely think of what else to try.

Comment: You have 1407 rep and 59 questions. You could put a bounty on 27 of them - I think you can afford to lose 50 reputation (not karma, we're not eBay). The system has a way to get attention, and if you don't want to use it, we can't really help.

Comment: It's possible people just don't know, but you could make the title a bit closer to your actual question. How do I display the layout vs. Indicator not showing correct layout after change in terminal.